# qml and import version : impact on performance?

Tags: qt, qml

Does QML import version is necessary to achieve better performance?

What I want to ask is :

Does `import QtQuick 2.9` can lead to better performance than `import QtQuick 2.0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't have any difference.

The only real difference between two different import versions of the same module is which new types and properties will be available to your code. Those new types and properties [will still be registered with the engine](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemsmodule.cpp?id=2e25ec139d6b2394650b165e71eba246423fb492#n176), but just won't be available if the import version in your QML isn't high enough for the version with which they were registered in C++.